# Minimalistic Ubuntu install without desktop for USB

Tags: nvidia, usb, ubuntu-minimal

I'm looking for a Ubuntu installation that runs from a USB flash drive. I do not want a desktop, all I need is a shell. It should be as small and fast as possible.

I currently work with Debian on a CubieBoard (cubian) and I really like it. I now bought a new system which has an intel CPU & a nVidia GPU. I was advised to switch to Ubuntu for better driver support.

Is there such an ISO image for USB? or maybe a way to create it myself (with limited Linux knowledge)?

Thanks in advance for your time!

Comment: "I do not want a desktop, all I need is a shell. It should be as small and fast as possible." in this case you could probably boot Ubuntu Server Edition. Regardless of the name, it's a minimal Ubuntu version with a prompt only as default. If not, try Lubuntu or Xubuntu for desktops (but very light desktops) if that is tolerable.

Comment: @bigbadonk420 This is more of an answer than and comment.

Comment: Well it's such a non-answer I would feel bad getting karma for it. A good answer would entail how to put Ubuntu on a USB and have it boot to prompt only by default. I think Ubuntu Server still gives you a menu and assumes that you actually want to install it (not run it live). Also there's the question of persistency which you likely want on a bootable USB Linux.

Comment: nim, this is not clear. I suppose you want an Ubuntu without desktop but you **do** need to run some graphic application on it, otherwise I can't understand why you are interested to the nVidia drivers. And BTW, which architecture (intel, Arm, whatever) is your PC?

Comment: it's an intel system. the reason why i need nvidia drivers (while not having a desktop) is, that the gpus are only used for calculations using the cuda 5.5 kit.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried installing one of the minimal Ubuntu iso's?

You can find them here:

- [MinimalCD](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD)

That way you can pick and choose exactly what features you want when installing.  I've successfully installed one of these on a USB that runs on a thin client with just 128Mb RAM (with a blackbox wm)

Comment: is it possible to install that to an USB stick? or do I need to download a special image?

Comment: Yes you can install it to USB via your computer, though you have to be very careful not to accidentally wipe your hard drive! A safer option, but requires more work is to install Ubuntu minimal to a VM and use Clonezilla to make a copy of the installed VM. The copy can then be installed to a USB by running Clonezilla in another VM with the USB plugged into the VM.

Comment: just a short question: does the MinimalCD somehow have a limitation for the number of GPUs? Everything wokrs fine when I run the system with two cards, but as soon as I add another card, nvidia-smi stops working and just gives me a:

`Unable to determine the device handle for GPU 0000:03:00.0: Unknown Error`

Comment: i switched from 12.10minimal to 13.10 server and now it's working as expected. thanks again.